# LinearModelFit with large number of coordinates

Tags: fitting

I am sorry if this is on here already (or if it is really easy!) I have looked and I am not sure how to go about it. I have data that is 1000 rows and each row contains 200 columns (x1,x2,x3,...)

I am trying to do linear regression of the form $y=\sum_{i=1}^{200}a_ix_i$, however seem to be unable to input it into Mathematica, am I meant to be doing something along the lines of the following:

```
LinearModelFit[data, {x01, x02, x03, ..., x199, x200}, {x01, x02, x03, ..., x199, x200}]
```

This doesn't seem like it should be the best way to do it! Please let me know where I am going wrong...

Comment: `LinearModelFit[{matrix, yVector}]`

Comment: Answer can only be as specific as the question. We could help you more, if you gave more specific, but simplified version of the problem

Comment: @Johu thank you for your reply, but the answer provided by Coolwater was good for what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning [a great comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173057/linearmodelfit-with-large-number-of-coordinates#comment454334_173057) into an answer.

All linear models are of the form $\vec{y}=\hat{A}\vec{x}$ and $\vec{x}$ can be a long vector. While this problem can be put into a form `LinearModelFit[{{x11,c12,...,y1},{x21,x22,...,y2},...},{f1,f2,...},{x1,x2,...}]` it might be more useful to use another supported form `LinearModelFit[{m,v}]`, where `m` is the *design matrix* and `v` is the *response vector*. See the examples in the [`LinearModelFit` documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearModelFit.html).

You could solve your Least-Square problem directly by finding a pseudo inverse `PseudoInverse[A]`, but `LinearModelFit` has useful additional features for giving you statistics of the residuals.